# How to paginate multiple collections in jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

Trying to get Jekyll collections to paginate using jekyll-paginate-v2 but I'm getting some odd behaviour where it uses the layout in the first pagination request it finds for all pages.

So for instance I have a number of different collections and for each collection I have a a folder with an index that is the same name as the collection but without the underscore.
So my events collection has `_events` with my markdown files and `events` with `index.html` that should display that collection. I have the same for "gallery" and "results" collections.

If I only activate pagination for one collection it works fine. As soon as I activate it for more than one the generated index.html's for every collection appear to use the first one it finds (in alphabetical order).

I've tested this by renaming folders and moving the pagination using index.html's around. Whichever index.html it hits first with pagination enabled becomes the one used for all of my index.html's that have collections enabled. Even if its in the root and called something else the same thing still happens.

My index.html's have similar front matter and pagination logic which is basically:

```
---
layout: page
title: Results
pagination:
  enabled: true
  collection: results
---
    
{% for result in paginator.posts %}
    <a href="{{ result.url }}">
        <h1 class="title results">
            {{ result.title }}
        </h1>
        <h6 class="date results">
            {{ result.date | date: "%A, %B %e, %Y at %I:%M%P" }}
        </h6>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hard to know without a repo, but one potential cause would be that the pagination is working for all, but overwriting eachother. Try setting different `permalink`s for each paginate page like this example: https://github.com/sverrirs/jekyll-paginate-v2/blob/master/examples/02-category/categories/byname.md

Comment: Running into the same issue, but looking into details I find that paginator updates, but page.content of the respective page is always overwritten with the first one. So different paginators on each of the pages, but the same page.content - very strange.